# Get data from PostgreSQL function to java

Tags: java, function, postgresql

I have written a simple function in `PostgreSQL` database. From my `JAVA` source code I am calling this function like

```
SELECT getData('active');
```

I am getting the data correct but the table header of the dataset is showing my function name (`getdata`) not `userid` and `username`. In this situation how I can get data?

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION getData(value text) 
RETURNS  TABLE(
    userid integer,
    username varchar(50)
) AS -- text AS --
$body$
DECLARE
    fullsql TEXT;
    records RECORD;
    exeQuery TEXT;
BEGIN

fullsql:= 'SELECT userid, username from user_index where status='''value'''';

exeQuery := 'SELECT * FROM (' || fullsql || ') AS records';

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE exeQuery;

END
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Currently the output is

```
getdate
--------------
501,alexanda
502,cathie
```

But I want to output like:

```
userid  username
------|---------
501,alexanda
502,cathie
```

i am trying to acheive following:

```
SELECT usr.username FROM cust_invoice_index as inv
INNER JOIN
(SELECT getdata('active')) as usr ON (usr.userid=inv.userid_edit)
```

Following query is working fine:

```
SELECT usr.username FROM cust_invoice_index as inv
INNER JOIN
(SELECT userid, username from user_index where status='active') as usr ON (usr.userid=inv.userid_edit)
```

Comment: What do you mean table headers? What does output look like currently?

Comment: Please post the query you are using.

Comment: Is this output from postgres command line or is it from javacode? If from javacode, please post your code

Comment: @SpartanElite 1st problem I am facing calling function within another function of database. Once it's done then I will try to achieve it from JavaCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your function returns a result set you should be using `select * from getdata('active')`.

Don't put calls to set returning functions into the select list.

```
SELECT usr.username 
FROM cust_invoice_index as inv
 JOIN (SELECT * FROM getdata('active')) as usr ON usr.userid=inv.userid_edit
```

Comment: So silly I am. It's so simple and I was thinking a complex way!! Thanks man. It's working fine.