# Reformat output of PostgreSQL function data

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

I have created following function in PostgreSQL database

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION getSR15ReportData(value text) 
RETURNS  TABLE(
    userid integer,
    username varchar(50)
) AS -- text AS --
$body$
DECLARE
    fullsql TEXT;
    records RECORD;
    exeQuery TEXT;
BEGIN

fullsql:= 'SELECT userid, username from user_index where status='''value'''';

exeQuery := 'SELECT * FROM (' || fullsql || ') AS records';

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE exeQuery;

END
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It's giving me output as follow:

```
getdate
--------------
501,alexanda
502,cathie
```

But I need output like:

```
userid  username
------|---------
501,alexanda
502,cathie
```

Comment: seems he separated the questions but still references the reformatting of the output in his other question.

Answer (score 0):

I was silly about this question. It was so simple. Thanks [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name). He has solved this on my another question [Get data from PostgreSQL function to java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661349/get-data-from-postgresql-function-to-java)

Just need to call the function:

`SELECT * FROM getdata('active')`

The full query will look like:

```
SELECT usr.username 
FROM cust_invoice_index as inv
 JOIN (SELECT * FROM getdata('active')) as usr ON usr.userid=inv.userid_edit
```